# Spot removal tool

Tags: post-production

I took videos with my DSLR and then saw that there is a speck of dust in my sensor. With stills I can use Photoshop's or Lightroom's "Spot removal tool".

Is there spot removal feature in video software? What is it? (Does Adobe Premiere have it?)

Answer (score 1):

There is not a spot heal tool in PremierePro, but there are a couple of things that you can try.

**If the spot is on a stationary portion of the video clip, you can...**

1. Export a frame using the frame export button [image] located under the program monitor.
2. Then clone the spot out in Photoshop using your retouch tool of choice.
3. Erase all of the frame except for the area that has been retouched, and save as a transparent PNG or PSD
4. Place your fixed frame (previously created PNG or PSD) over the portion of you video in your sequence.

**If the spot is in an area that has a lot of motion, you can...**

1. Open the video in Photoshop and use the healing tool to frame by frame clone out the blemish.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that it's possible to keyframe the motion of the clone stamp tool (or healing brush) on video in Photoshop.  The first time I read your post, I thought you were talking about opening each frame individually.

Comment: Also like to point out that there's a good tutorial on how to do this with both Photoshop and After Effects on Lynda.com Unfortunately requires subscription, but you could sign up for a free trial. http://www.lynda.com/After-Effects-tutorials/Repairing-Enhancing-Video/149128-2.html

Comment: The reason I didn't say anything about keyframing is that he said the spot was from dust on the sensor, so it won't be moving very much!